# Properly format json payload

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I am trying to format json payload as such, but i am getting a syntax error at the Params property

```
   mailer.send2(new PayoutEmailModel
                    {
                        medium = "email",
                        name = "sap_finance_supplier_payout",
                        @params = @"{""supplier"":""" + BeneficiaryName + """,""lastfourdigits"":""" + AccountNo + """,""amount"":""" + Amount + """,""valuedate"":""" + BeneficiaryName + """,""time"":""" + BeneficiaryName + """}",
                        recipient = "dapo.olotu@konga.com",
                        sender = "no-reply@konga.com",
                        subject = "Payment Notification",
                        sender_id = "Konga"
                    });
```

Edit,
I need @Params proper to render as below

```
{"supplier":"foo","lastfourdigits":"foo","amount":"foo","valuedate":"foo","time":"foo"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Dinesh is right, you probably won't get the results you expect by doing it your way. But, to answer your question, the syntax error is because you start a new string with every `+` operator but you do not prepend with a new `@`:

@"{""supplier"":""" + BeneficiaryName + @""",""lastfourdigits"":""" + AccountNo + @""",""amount"":""" + Amount + @""",""valuedate"":""" + BeneficiaryName + @""",""time"":""" + BeneficiaryName + @"""}",

Answer (score 1):

Try using anonymous type

```
mailer.send2(new PayoutEmailModel
    {
        medium = "email",
        name = "sap_finance_supplier_payout",
        params = new { supplier = BeneficiaryName, lastfourdigits = AccountNo, amount = Amount, valuedate = BeneficiaryName, time = BeneficiaryName},
        recipient = "dapo.olotu@konga.com",
        sender = "no-reply@konga.com",
        subject = "Payment Notification",
        sender_id = "Konga"
    });
```